# Sandboxing my App with Scripting Bridge to send email

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sandbox

I'm using a scripting bridge for sending mails from my Mac App. Now I need to sandbox the app and sending mails is not longer working while sandboxing is enabled.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Thanks,
Andreas

Code: 
`

```
/* create a Scripting Bridge object for talking to the Mail application */
    MailApplication *mail = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Mail"];


/* create a new outgoing message object */
MailOutgoingMessage *emailMessage =
[[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"outgoing message"] alloc]
 initWithProperties:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [self.subjectField stringValue], @"subject",
  [[self.messageContent textStorage] string], @"content",
  nil]];

/* add the object to the mail app  */
[[mail outgoingMessages] addObject: emailMessage];
...
```

`

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the ScriptingBridge with Sandboxing enabled. Please file a bug report. This is what Apple recommends, if Sandboxing is a problem for you and there are no other solutions. They might add entitlements (not just *temporary exceptions*) for the ScriptingBridge, but as of now there is no further information available.

There are [Entitlements Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/ApplicationSandboxingEntitlementKeys/ApplicationSandboxingEntitlementKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH7-SW1), especially the `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` key, you can add to your Entitlements.plist file, but the key for Apple Events is a *temporary exception*.
Unfortunately, I was unable to get ScriptingBridge working even with the correct entitlements set. I hope you're luckier than me.

Apple is going to require Sandboxing for **all** apps submitted to the Mac App Store starting on the *1st of November*!

`com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events`

Comment: You CAN use the ScriptingBridge with Sandboxing enabled. However, you will only be able to compose an e-mail.  Sending an e-mail does not appear to be allowed by Sandboxed apps.  See my new answer for a sample project.

Comment: Cool, thanks! That doesn't solve the temporary exception problem, though.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your Entitlements.plist, I tested It's ok.I can get selected mail from Mail now.

```
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <array>
    <string>com.apple.mail</string>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified Apple's SBSendEmail sample application to be Sandboxed and can successfully compose an e-mail.  It appears that it is not possible to send the e-mail, but at least you could set everything up for the user just to press send.

https://github.com/Whiffer/SBSendEmail

Answer (score -1):

```
of mac os x 10.8 and later, it has changed:

<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.mail</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.mail.compose</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```