# Scripting Bridge and Sandbox

Tags: osx-lion, sandbox, scripting-bridge

I would like to make an app which would need to get the list of the open tabs in Safari, using the Scripting Bridge. Is it then possible to sandbox such an app so that it can be sold on the App Store?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am also trying to use the mail app with scripting bridge, and submit the app to the mac appStore.

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't found a solution for this f****** problem!

Comment: I am afraid it can not.  See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287060/sandboxing-my-app-with-scripting-bridge-to-send-email

Answer (score 2):

Maybe -- it’s a question of Store policy.  Technically, it’s simple: add this entitlement to your application:

```
"com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events" = ( "com.apple.safari" );
```

Your application can now send any Apple events (which are what Scripting Bridge uses) to Safari.  However, you’ll have to justify your use of that entitlement, and that’s where the Store policy comes in.  In theory, that entitlement is being replaced by `com.apple.security.scripting-targets`, which is new in Mountain Lion, but it’s a gradual process, and Safari doesn’t support it yet.